# Foreign key issues with id "ALL"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 table

Table 1:

```
  ID_A| ClmnA
     1 | A
     2 | B
     3 | C
```

Table 2:

```
ID_B|ID_A
  H  | 3
  V  | 1
  K  | 1
```

There is a relation between table 1 and table 2. The thing is all the id in the first table have one index "ALL" so it's going to be like this in the second table.

```
    ID_B |ID_A
      H  | 3
      V  | 1
      K  | 1 
     All | 1
     All | 2
     All | 3
```

So the problem is I can't add them because of 2 things:

1. The **ID_B** is a primary key so I can't add multiple **"All"** in it.
2. Even if I delete the primary key in **ID_B** I can't add the because I have a thousand of rows.

Comment: I can't make out what it is you're trying to accomplish, much less what problems you're running into. Where is `All` coming from? Why would you even add it to the second table? What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? Reducing the problem to essentials is nice, but this one has been reduced a little too much.

Comment: **ALL** is a value that i need it in drop down list .. my client want to add it .. the actuel problem is that i need to add "ALL" value in the seconde table  ..  bcuz all the ID in the first table have one same value calling "ALL" .. i need it in a dropdownlist .i will give u example .. whene user select ID=1 : the dropdownlist will fill by ("V","K","ALL").. to do that i need to add "ALL" in the seconde table .. but there is a problem as i'm saying in the question .thanks

Comment: Why would you need to add `All` to the actual table just because someone wants it in a dropdown? The usual approach is to add it as strictly visual thing (after items have been added to it from the DB) and then treat it specially with application logic (leave out the filter). It isn't an entity in the database and shouldn't be stored -- as you have found out, with your current structure it *cannot* be stored. If your application cannot make its database binding more sophisticated, the alternative would be to define a view that gives this result (adding the `All` rows virtually).

Answer (score 0):

Use a query to get the results:

```
select id_b, id_a
from table2
union all
select 'All', id_a
from table1;
```

For your application, you can wrap this in a view:

```
create view v_table2 as
    select id_b, id_a
    from table2
    union all
    select 'All', id_a
    from table1;
```